# Kendo AutoComplete set selected object programmatically

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, autocomplete

In auto-complete selected element is an object "user". 
When filling the form, I would like to set the object in auto-complete as the selected one in a way, that `$("#" + controlId).data("kendoAutoComplete").dataItem()` would return selected object.

`$("#" + controlId).data("kendoAutoComplete").value("test")` is setting only what is displayed but not the object behind.

Here is the definition:

```
$("#" + controlId).kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: minLength,
    enforceMinLength: true,
    dataTextField: "Calculated",
    filter: "contains",
    template: '<span class="k-state-default"><p>#: data.FirstName # #: data.LastName # - #: data.Login #</p><p>#: data.Email #</p></span>',
    dataSource: {
      type: "json",
      serverFiltering: true,
      transport: {
        read: serviceUrl,
        parameterMap: function (data, type) {
          return { filter: $("#" + controlId).val() };
        }
      },
      schema: {
        parse: function (response) {
          var length = response.length;
          var dataItem;
          var idx = 0;

          for (; idx < length; idx++) {
            dataItem = response[idx];
            dataItem.Calculated = dataItem.FirstName + " " + dataItem.LastName;
          }
          return response;
        }
      }
    },
    filtering: function (e) {
      if (!e.filter.value) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

So as far as I understand your issue, you want to select an existing object in the list and use it afterwards.

A solution would be this example below:

HTML:

```
  <input id="autocomplete" />
  <button onclick="addIt()">Add me</button>
  <button onclick="getIt()">Test me</button>
```

Init autocomplete:

```
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Dzeko", nat: "Bosnia" },
    { name: "Ronaldo", nat: "Portugal" },
    { name: "Messi", nat: "Argentina" },
    { name: "Muller", nat: "Germany" },
    { name: "Mbappe", nat: "France" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name"
});
```

Select and get selected user:

```
  var user = {name: "Dzeko", nat: "Bosnia" };

  var autocomplete = $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");

  function addIt(){
    autocomplete.search(user.name);
    autocomplete.select(autocomplete.ul.children().eq(0));
    autocomplete.trigger("change");
    autocomplete.close();
  }

  function getIt(){    
    console.log(autocomplete.dataItem());
  }
```

This way you will get the user object in console.log

Also a working dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/@sehaxx/OpIvOBOY
Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is strange. For search to work, I have to use: autoComplete.value(user.Login); But it is not selecting the first item from search nor it closes the drop down. I checked it, and selecting and closing is just happening to fast, before there are any results from service. Is there a way to wait for the results before selecting?

Comment: @Jacek can you add the code for selecting in service promise. That way it is called when your service is finished. Also this is an interesting link where you could write your custom logic: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/api

Comment: Than You so much for Your help. Unfortunately I' don't know how to run this search in promise service. Search is not returning a promise and it's async.

Comment: I see, you are correct it is not a promise. I just checked this it is not working in my test case but maybe for you it will work. https://www.telerik.com/forums/programmatic-search-then-select